# Почему Telethon не отправляет сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

в моем приложении происходят странные вещи, когда программа не запущенна сообщения в чат отправляются, когда запущенна бесконечная отправка, как это можно решить и с чем это связанно[image: вот так получается]

Comment: А где ваш код ?

Comment: Мне кажется дела не в коде, потому что у меня на ПК работает, а на ПК заказчика нет, предположительно это из-за впн

Comment: Тут вопрос не к telehon'у. У вас плохая связь, скорее всего из-за VPN. кружочек снизу отображается тогда, когда клиент телеграма не может отправить сообщение.

Comment: спасибо, значит это только из-за плохого соединения мой код ни в чем не виноват?